# IOS IN-APP purchase add In App Purchase items automatically

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase

I am developing an IPHONE application where multiple users can come and upload images,videos,audios etc such digital items for sales .

So now I am going for In App Purchase as I am dealing with digital items .

**My Question :** Is there any other way to do purchases other than IN-APP to avoid apple cut?

My next question is if I go for IN-APP users going to upload n number of  items(image,videos,audios) for each and every items Do I need to update in itunes say if users going to upload 1000 items for each items do i need to manually add items in inapp ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No, You should implement In-App purchase for doing this. If you implement any other way to purchase products in your App, Apple will reject your App.
2. No, Not possible. You need to update the items in iTunes connect for In-App purchase.

Comment: This. Any mechanism other than IAP violates section 11.2 of the App Store Review Guidelines. You might get away with it, but even if it did initially get approved, your app would be in constant danger of being pulled from the App Store.

Comment: Thanks you so much Midhun MP , This update of item in iTunes connect should be done manually? is there ant automated way to update the item in iTune. say if user upload a item can we do some automated way that it get updated into iTunes instead doing it manually

Comment: @user2185363: No, till now there is no way to update it automatically. You should do it manually :)

Comment: @user2185363: With Pleasure :)

Answer (score 0):

I think apple allow third party payment gateway like Paypal..you can use it in your app..

Answer (score 0):

Apple requires that all digital goods purchases be made via StoreKit, So this is not something that you could use the PayPal iOS SDK for anyway.

Well Apple only allows In app purchases when you are using digital goods.

You can only use for example paypal if you are selling non digital goods. For **Paypal** Check this [here](https://developer.paypal.com) and you can download source from [PayPal IOS SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK)

Note : Keep in mind all these guidelines first before using Paypal [general guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html)

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks you so much Midhun MP , This update of item in iTunes connect should be done manually? is there ant automated way to update the item in iTune. say if user upload a item can we do some automated way that it get updated into iTunes instead doing it manually

Comment: i am dealing with digital items like image, video , audio in this case can i do that with payPal which is a third party payment gateway . i learned apple do not allow third party payment for digital item purchase is that so?